# How to implement Parcelable for a class with String[] and byte[] fields?

Tags: android

I'm attempting to implement parcelable for the a class with following fields. Im getting an exception when attempting to create the class from the parcel (put in a bundle) on the fields String mStyle[] and byte[] mImage   .I'm not receiving any errors on these fields on writeToParcel-- what is the correct usage?. thanks much

```
      private String mClothingItemName;
        private String mColor;
    private String mPrint;
    private String mStyle[];
    private String mMaterial;
    private String mBrand;
    private String mStorageLocation;
    private String mOptionalDescription;

    private byte[] mImage;




    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeString(mClothingItemName);
        out.writeLong(mClothesId);
        out.writeString(mColor);
        out.writeString(mPrint);
        //out.writeStringArray(mStyle);
        out.writeString(mMaterial);
        out.writeString(mBrand);
        out.writeString(mStorageLocation);
        out.writeString(mOptionalDescription);
    //  out.writeByteArray(mImage);
    }


    private Clothes(Parcel in) {

        mClothingItemName = in.readString();
        mClothesId = in.readLong();
        mColor = in.readString();
        mPrint = in.readString();
//      in.readStringArray(mStyle);
        mMaterial = in.readString();
        mBrand = in.readString();
        mStorageLocation = in.readString();
        mOptionalDescription = in.readString();

        //in.readByteArray(mImage);

    }
```

Comment: which exception you are getting?

Comment: @Gopal rao ---02-07 06:41:51.653: E/AndroidRuntime(3150): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 06:41:51.653: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):  at android.os.Parcel.readStringArray(Parcel.java:931)
02-07 06:41:51.653: E/AndroidRuntime(3150):  at abacus.dmbasys.closetorganizer.Clothes.<init>(Clothes.java:323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the website [link](http://parcelabler.com/) , from a class will generate the code to make it parceable.

Comment: @TeRRo--thanks ,i tried this now but it parceled all the other fields and gave the following error for these two fields -----The following variables were not recognized (syntax error?):

    private String[] mStyle
    private byte[] mImage

Comment: Your've copied the code of the class and you've stuck on the website? To copy both variables, the constructor, getter and setter.

Comment: i just copied the variables and stuck on website (im implementing a couple more interfaces in this class i will leave that out ?),ok i will try now with variables, the constructor, getter and setter

Comment: --nope,its still not happy with these two fields even with the constructor,getter and setter.

Comment: i changed the String[] to String,anyway they are comma separated. and saved the image in a file (for this scenario) and with filename(String) got rid of the byte array --  the site is good some of the byte field based type indication was extra helpful